# User defined service in cloud foundry

Tags: spring-boot, service, cloud-foundry, pcf

How to create the user defined service in cloud Foundry. I have spring boot app which i want to host as a service. I want this application to be exposed as service so that, the other apps that bind to this would use it by default.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create user defined services using Cloud Foundry CLI commands.

```
cf cups SERVICE_INSTANCE -p '{"username":"admin","password":"password"}'
```

Doc Link: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html